# How are multiple line inputs handled?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a problem that is asking me to create a function with one parameter (num) to obtain a particular value from an input that looks like this:

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

The first line is the number of elements in the array and the array itself is on the second line.

I don't really understand this input format. Is num supposed to be two lines? Suppose the function was to find the max value of the array. How exactly should I interpret what num is? Would the function run line by line and thus would num = [1] for the first line and num = [1,2,3,4] for the second line?

Comment: you got some answers, please do not vandalize the question. instead add some more information, if necessary.

Comment: I deleted the question because I asked an incorrect one. I had misread what was being asked of me.

Answer (score 2):

I usually handle this type of input by splitting 2 times. The first time you split by newline, and take the second line, then split the second line by spaces.

```js
function getArray(num){
    return num.split(`\n`)[1].split(` `)
}
```

This returns an array of the wanted values, in your example `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. From there, you can use a max function that takes in an array for example

```js
function maxOfArray(array){
    let max = array[0]
    for(element of array){
        if(element > max)
            max = element
    }
    return max
}
```

And call it using the function that converts it to the array:

```js
const input = `4
1 2 3 4`
console.log(maxOfArray(getArray(input))
```

Comment: You can use `Math.max(...array)` instead of `maxOfArray(array)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<textarea>` for get number in format:

```js
 $('#btn').click(function () {
 
    var value = $('#array-text').val();

    var line1 = value.split('\n')[0];
    console.log(line1);
    
    var line2 = value.split('\n')[1];
    console.log(line2);

    var array = line2.split(' ')
    console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="array-text"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="btn">show</button>
```